# Laravel method to get input parameter without trim any value

Tags: laravel, post, request

For Laravel post request's parameter get with `$request->all();`

This function itself does trimming for the request parameter if there is any preceding space.
I try to use `$_POST` instead of `$this->request->all()`;  it is not trimming any request parameter and works as expected.

`$_POST` is not safe to use.

please share suggestions/ideas how can I do that without trimming any value ?

Comment: What is the use case here? What is the input you're trying to get "untrimmed"? Can you "untrim" it yourself, i.e. if it's just leading spaces that you need (for some unknown reason), you could use the `str_pad()` function in PHP, or similar. Matias is correct below in indicating that this is weird behaviour, and disabling this middleware can cause other issues (spaces where there shouldn't be spaces can be a tricky error to track down)

Answer (score 2):

You have HTTP middlewares, one of those trims the data. Check this: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9ae75b58a1ffc00ad36bf1e877fe2bf9ec601b82/app/Http/Kernel.php#L22

```
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array<int, class-string|string>
 */
protected $middleware = [
    // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];
```

You can see there is a `\App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class`, you have to remove that one.

Comment: removal of \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class , it help.
but it will impact to all the calls of $this->request->all(), I need to have untrimmed data at one post request only,

Comment: Well, that is very weird, you could remove the middleware on the controller's constructor, but that is 100% weird and non-common

Answer (score 2):

The trimming of your input value happens to be due to an active global middleware. The `\App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings` middleware to be exact.

Since you say you do not want to disable the middleware for your entire application, you should look into disabling it only for a specific route or routes. You can do so in two ways:

1. Single route:

```php
Route::post('my-route', 'MyRouteController@myRoute')->withoutMiddleware(['trimStrings']);
```

2. Group of routes:

```php
Route::withoutMiddleware([\App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class])->group(function () {
    Route::post('my-route', 'MyRouteController@myRoute');

    // Add additional routes within this group.
});
```

However, please note that the `withoutMiddleware` method can only remove route middleware and does not apply to global middleware. Since the `TrimStrings` is by default a global middlewere, you will still need to remove it from the `$middleware` array in the `app/Http/Kernel.php` file and add the `TrimStrings` middleware manually again for all routes where you do not want to remove it. To do so, use a similar looking route group syntax as demonstrated in option 2, like so:

```php
Route::middleware([\App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class])->group(function () {
    // Place all the routes you already had here.
});
```

You can also take a look at the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/middleware#excluding-middleware

Answer (score 1):

If the list of fields to exclude in the middleware class (as mentioned by siux) is too large, in your AppServiceProvider class you can exclude the TrimStrings middleware based on the $request as follows:

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

    TrimStrings::skipWhen(function ($request) {
        return $request->is(['customer/customer-list', 'job/job-list', 'product/product-list']);
    });
}
```

This also works for global middleware

Answer (score 0):

As of laravel 5+ you should be able to add fields in the middleware exclude list (app/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php) that should not be trimmed, which might be a sensible approach over excluding the middleware completely.